# I want to create a mobile website in addition to native apps using phonegap. Is it sensible to use the same codebase?

Tags: php, jquery, cordova

I want to have a mobile-friendly website, in addition to a native app for iphone/android using phonegap.  I'm currently using PHP (specifically CodeIgniter but that's not as important) and jQuery for the mobile website.

I'm thinking that the website and the phonegap codebase can use the same PHP back-end for server requests but the front-end must be somewhat different since phonegap has proprietary javascript to access native functionality (camera, accelerometer, etc) that a browser couldn't access.  For this reason, I think the front-end must be developed separately for the mobile site vs. for phonegap.

Does this make sense?  Am I missing something that would allow me to use the same phonegap codebase as the mobile site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where I work, we developed our mobile website and Android App with the same codebase except for the views and UI. Everything on the web side is in pure JS and HTML. We have a sever side API that we request data from and then template it using Mustache.

We used Titanium for the Android App, but found that framework to have more cons than pros to use. So for the iPhone app upgrade we're using PhoneGap. It took us a few hours but the mobile site ported over exactly the way it works in browser, to the native iPhone app created by PhoneGap. In short, It's absolutely possible but you have to develop the site in JS, all the logic, to have it port over easily to PhoneGap.

Also, just a recommendation, you should try using [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) instead of jQuery. It's aerogel weight, has the majority of jQuery functionality without all the IE bull and it uses the familiar $ symbol as a namespace. Much more suitable for mobile development.

Specifically, PhoneGap has plugins that you write. There's two sides to this, one JS file which will match the plugin that you write for the native Obj C or Android file. The plugins are modular, so you can plug them in for the native apps and out for the site.